# Using Views to Filter on a property of all relationships

Tags: views

Let's say I have a node *Exercise* that has multiple-entity reference field, pointing to *Skill* nodes.  Those *Skill* nodes have a field *Skill Score*.  I want to only show the *Exercises* where **every** *Skill* referenced has a *Skill Score* > 3.  Is there a way to do this with views?

Comment: I think it's not possible with only views ui without any custom code.

Comment: Aggregation doesn't seem to help, maybe it can be done with https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator